# What is the correct relationship between active, reactive and apparent power in non-linear AC systems?

Tags: ac, harmonics, apparent-power

I am somewhat troubled by the 'basic' formula that describes the relationship between apparent power (S), active power (P) and reactive power (Q) in AC systems. This formula is `S^2 = P^2 + Q^2` and makes sense to me in linear systems with or without phase shifts. But quite some modern loads contain large amounts of harmonic currents that in my view can not create any work (active power) if the voltage is purely sinusoidal. But if apparent power is defined as `S = V_rms * I_rms`, the harmonic content adds up in `I_rms`, thus making `S > P`. A simple way to think about this, is that the difference can be called reactive power `Q` by adhering to `S^2 = P^2 + Q^2`. But I wonder whether that would be correct. Since I always believed Q is defined as reactive power with the vector component of the current perpendicular to the voltage by the relationships `P = V_rms * I_rms * cos(phi) and Q = V_rms * I_rms * sin(phi)`. I subsequently would believe higher harmonics in currents combined with the same harmonics in the voltage could have these relationships as well, such that higher harmonics could create both active and reactive power. But if the voltage is pure sinusoidal, it has no higher harmonics and the current harmonics will not create reactive power (nor active power) in my view. It would be great if this was generally seen as 'distortion power' `D` that adds to `P` and `Q` in a quadratic way (analogous to displacement and distortion power factors), but I have not seen this.

My question is whether there is a definition of power generated by harmonics that will fix the difference between active and apparent power. And I am wrong assuming that if that difference (in a quadratic way) is called `Q`, that the definition of reactive power should be different?

I have made a non-linear system that has a sinusoidal voltage and a square current that are in-phase and I did some calculations to get an idea of the 'missing' power. The active power is in-line with what I expect and I can calculate it in two ways. Firstly by integrating the voltage and current over a multiple of their period and dividing it by the elapsed time (simple average of the product in this case actually). Secondly by multiplying the RMS voltage by the RMS value of the fundamental harmonic of the current, knowing I do not have to multiply that by `cos(phi)` since these are in-phase. These values match and I have showed them in the output of my copied script below. There is no active power by higher harmonics, since the voltage does not have higher harmonics. And the same is true for reactive power of both fundamental and higher  harmonics: this is zero for the fundamental harmonic since the voltage and current are in-line. And is zero for higher harmonics given that the harmonic values of the voltage are zero and thus the product will be zero.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2))
def fundamental(x):
    N = len(x)//periods
    X = abs(2/N*sp.fft.fft(x, N))
    return X[1]*np.sin(w*t)

freq = 60
w = 2*np.pi*freq
periods = 4
t = np.linspace(0, periods/freq, 10000)
v = np.sin(w*t)

i = sp.signal.square(w*t)


plt.plot(t, v, label='v(t)')
plt.plot(t, i, label='i(t)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print('RMS Voltage =', rms(v),
      '\nRMS Current =', rms(i))
print('Active Power:',
     '\n  integral of v*i of one period divided by that period = ', np.mean(v*i))
print('Active Power by the fundamental current (phase angle is zero):',
     '\n  V_1_rms * I_1_rms = ', rms(v) * rms(fundamental(i)))
print('Active Power by higher harmonic currents:',
     '\n  V_n_rms * I_n_rms for n>=2 = 0 * I_n_rms = 0')
print('Apparent Power:',
     '\n  V_rms * I_rms =', rms(v) * rms(i))
```

[image]

Based on this example I would come to the following result for 'missing' power:
[image]

Is there a definition for this value that I calculated? It is quite substantial at almost 50% of the active power.

Comment: "But if the voltage is pure sinusoidal, it has no higher harmonics and the current harmonics will not create reactive power in my view." Did you mean active? You can indeed treat each harmonic independently: apply Parseval's theorem.  Related, though not an exact answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/633117/311631

Comment: I mean both active and reactive indeed. Thank you. I updated the question.  As for treating the harmonics independently, that causes my ‘issue’ of not just calling non-active power simply reactive. I understand the mathematical side of integrals of products of sinusoids with different frequencies canceling out to zero. So no harmonics create any reactive power nor does the fundamental current. Still I am afraid many people will call this ‘distortion power’ reactive. And I am looking whether there is a graceful solution to this discrepancy.

Comment: S, P, and Q are only defined for fundamental... All other are used for "distortion".

Comment: True power is what it is (harmonics or not). Apparent power is what it is (harmonics or not) and, if you want to call what makes up the difference reactive power, then so be it. Are you trying to fix something that isn't broken I wonder? Is there any use for reactive power that shouts at needing a strict definition?

Comment: @Antonio51 and Andy aka are stating opposite things. My math is broken by it. And most energy meters add all harmonics to P automatically, have 90 degree shift for measuring Q and mostly measure the fundamental. Whereas S is based on rms values of V and I that include all harmonics. Doesn’t add up.

Comment: @Antonio51 A more general definition exists, which reduces to that in the sinusoidal steady-state case. Simply taking S = Vrms * Irms and P = avg(V(t) * I(t)) works for any frequencies within the averaging/integration window.

Comment: This was my point of linking the answer (which applied the definitions to DC), but I guess the significance was missed.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am not sure, because then (with harmonics), P and Q should not be "orthogonal". But perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @JeromeBu1982 I don't think that they are opposite things. Mine is just for defining PF. Harmonics are generally a "side effect", because they are "eliminated" by filters. And the "mains" does not like harmonics ... you pay for them.

Comment: @TimWilliams “ Simply taking S = Vrms * Irms and P = avg(V(t) * I(t)) works”. I agree, that is the calculation I did. My question is what we call the (quadratic) difference between resulting S and P

Comment: @Antonio51 I concur with you that P and Q should have an orthogonal property. Also agree the rest is just ‘distortion’ and we could fix the a lot by agreeing to S^2=P^2+Q^2+D^2. But we are not…

Comment: @JeromeBu1982 S^2=P^2+Q^2+D^2. I think this is correct (Parseval theorem or identity?). It is a long time ago, I used some power analyzer. Don't remember how all parameters were measured ... Will search.

Comment: Here are, for reference, the measured parameters with Fluke 430 Power Analyser  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecbnI.png

Comment: See this post answer of user80875 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/528110/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-reactive-power-in-non-sinusoidal-steady-state-w?rq=1

Comment: @Antonio51: Wow! that list of the Fluke is conciseI have access to a 435. Will experiment on highly harmonic situations (bridge rectifier). So they call my “missing power” “VA Harmonics” and describe Q as pure displacement of the fundamental.  Would that be the answer?  Plus I think the fact that most people disagree. Such is clear. (If some can upvote comments that are liked, we get some insight in thoughts. Plus please upvote my question if you feel it is asked correctly)

Comment: It was a very good question ........................... It does remember me of some "good" things as a teacher ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing power can simply be called 'Distortion Power' \$D\$, unit VA. Per the following equation:
$$ V_{rms}^2I_{rms}^2 = S^2 = D^2 +\sum_h P_h^2+\sum_h Q_h^2 $$ , where h is the number of the harmonic (source: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/489895/199042)

In the somewhat extreme example in the question, with a sinusoidal voltage and an in-phase square wave current, the RMS values, active power (P) and the 'missing' power (D) were calculated by a 10,000 sample simulation. These values are: (rounded to 3 decimals):
$$ 
\begin{matrix}
V_{rms} & = & 0.707\\
I_{rms} & = & 1\\
S & = & 0.707\\
P & = & 0.637\\
Q & = & 0\\
D & = & 0.308
\end{matrix}
$$

These values are correct and can also be derived mathematically:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle V_{rms} &=& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} \mbox{    (known quantity for sinusoid with amplitude 1)}\\
I_{rms} &=& 1  \mbox{ (sqrt of area under the squared values divided by period)}\\
S &=& \displaystyle V_{rms}*I_{rms}\\
&=&\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} \\
P^2 &=& \displaystyle\sum_hP_h^2 \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_h V_h^2 I_h^2\cos(\theta_h) \\
&=& \displaystyle V_1^2I_1^2\\\
& & \mbox{since } V_h=0 \mbox{ for } h>=2 \mbox{ and }\theta_1=0^\circ
\end{matrix}
$$

That leaves the calculation of the fundamental current \$I_1\$. This can be done by the fourier series for a square wave f(t). By expressing a square wave f(t) as an infinite sum of sineways with harmonic frequencies per:
$$ 
f(t)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{h=1,3,5,...}^\infty\frac{1}{h}\sin{\frac{h\pi t}{T}} 
$$
Where \$I_1\$ is the RMS value of the fundamental current, we can call \$i_1(t)\$ the fundamental current in the time domain. This leads to:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle i_1(t) = \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{h}\sin{\frac{h\pi t}{T}}\ \mbox{ with } h=1 \\
\end{matrix}$$
\$I_1\$ is then simply \$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\$ times the amplitude of \$i_1(t)\$:
$$ 
I_1 =  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{4}{\pi}
$$
Thus:
$$
\begin{matrix}
 P &=& V_1\cdot I_1\\
 & =& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{4}{\pi}\\
&=&\frac{2}{\pi}\\
&\approx & 0.637
\end{matrix}
$$
\$D\$ is then simply:
$$
\begin{matrix}
D^2&=&S^2-P^2-Q^2\\
&=&{(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})}^2 - (\frac{2}{\pi})^2\\
D&\approx &0.308
\end{matrix}
$$
And for reactive power:
$$
\begin{matrix}
Q^2 &=& \displaystyle\sum_hQ_h^2 \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_h V_h^2 I_h^2\sin(\theta_h) \\
&=& \displaystyle 0\\
& & \mbox{since } V_h=0 \mbox{ for } h>=2 \mbox{ and }\theta_1=0^\circ
\end{matrix}
$$

This confirms the notion that the equation \$S^2=P^2+Q^2\$ simply does not hold in non-linear AC systems. It is true that quite some power can be in the form of non-reactive, higher harmonic power while not creating any work. Still many will call the quadratic difference between \$S\$ and \$P\$ simply \$Q\$. This is incorrect for many modern non-linear AC systems. \$Q\$ is the reactive component, orthogonal to the active power.

Comment: P, Q, and D are all "orthogonal" in geometric representations (3 axes) ...

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to orthogonality. I used it implicitly. Now with Parceval’s theorem it is explicit. It makes the formulas work. And yet, I think the classical thinking of Q is just related the displacement of the fundamental. With the risk of putting the reactive harmonics in the “D bucket”. That would break orthogonality again. I am interested still how modern text books separate the classical thinking of  displacement by machinery with the (mostly?) non-displaced harmonics by modern switched power supplies

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I happened across this reference which may be handy:

"Power measurement techniques for non-sinusoidal conditions", S. Svensson, doctoral thesis, Chalmers University of Technology, Electric Power Engineering, Göteborg, Sweden, 1999 
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/70557608.pdf 
A review of reactive power accounting methods is provided in the first section.

See also: [How to calculate reactive power of a capacitor with a current waveform which consists of a sum of sinusoids?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/602870/how-to-calculate-reactive-power-of-a-capacitor-with-a-current-waveform-which-con)

Comment: 150 pages with vary variable input on this subject. Good link!